# Installing mimcrosoft's SAPI in code blocks or QT and manipulate it

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, codeblocks, speech-to-text

I'm trying to create a speech to text converter program that can be used in teaching. I earlier created one using Google's speech recognition API, it works fine but the user must have internet to use it.On making a followup about making an offline one i found that Microsoft's SAPI 5.3 or 5.4 might be a solution. but it's just a library and i have to install it to code::blocks or qt IDE in order to make use of it without visual basic. I have never installed a library in code::blocks nor in qt IDE, so any help in library installation and guidance in utilization will be appreciated. Or even a better solution.

Comment: Is using Microsoft Visual Studio an available option for you? It does after all, cost just as much to purchase as the other 2 and for things like this, is far, far easier. It's debugger alone was enough to convince me to install it.

Comment: Microsoft visual studio is too heavy, and why should i download all the visual studio with about(18GB) while i need only one library which's several Megabytes.

Comment: I agree that it's a big download. Simply put, because from a cursory look, there doesn't appear to be an import lib for SAPI that works with MinGW.  Without one, you have basically 2 options AFAIK. (0) Use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` to get a pointer to the functions you want, which you can then call if you tell the compiler enough about each function (bit of a pain in the backside) and (1) create an import lib yourself. A proposition which is also a pain in the proverbial - if it was easy for SAPI, I'd expect one to exist already.  http://www.mingw.org/wiki/createimportlibraries